# Beginning Javascript form validation

Tags: javascript

this is my first time posting.

I'm in a beginner Javascript class with the following assignment:

"Students are required to enter into a text box their course information in the following format:

AAA.111#2222_aa-1234

Your Web page will ask the user to type their information in a text box. The user will then click a form button named validate. If the format is correct a message will be generated below the button that reads "Correct Format".  If the format is incorrect a message will be generated that reads "Incorrect Format". "

After my first attempt, I got the following feedback:

"You do not need a form for this assignment .You only need a text box and a button. Place your function on your button (onClick event). You only need one function for this assignment. ﻿﻿﻿﻿ Your function should include getting the users input from the text box. You can use getElementById() and .value  it should also include the regular expression, and what to so if it is correct or wrong."

So far I have the following:

```js
function isValid(text) {
 var myRegExp = /([A-Z]{3})\.\d{3}#\d{4}_(sp|su|fa)-\d{4}/; 
 return (myRegExp.test(text);
 if (isValid(document.getElementById("course".value) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Correct Format";
 } else {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Incorrect Format"
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Chapter 6 Assignment</title>
</head>
<body> 
<p>Please enter your course information in the following format AAA.111#2222_aa-1234:</p>
<input type ="text" name ="course" id="course" />
<button onclick="isValid()">Validate</button>
<p id="output"></p>
<script src = "registerFourth.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So sorry if I am not posting this correctly.  My code is telling me I have a "Parsing Error: Unexpected Token" and when I fill in the text box and click Validate nothing happens. Thank you!

Comment: One thing I see, is your `return` statement should be after your if/else statement -- if you want to run those tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your approach.
1. Your isValid method expects text parameter which is not required
2. Your isValid method is recursive, I don't see why that is needed.

Please check below if it works for you.

```js
function isValid() {
 var myRegExp = /([A-Z]{3})\.\d{3}#\d{4}_(sp|su|fa)-\d{4}/;
  var text = document.getElementById("course").value;
  var match = myRegExp.test(text);
  if(match) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Correct Format";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Incorrect Format";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your course information in the following format AAA.111#2222_aa-1234:</p>
<input type ="text" name ="course" id="course" />
<button onclick="isValid()">Validate</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of syntax as well as function construction issues with this.

- You have a missing `)` in 2 lines - 
  `return (myRegExp.test(text);`
  and
  `if (isValid(document.getElementById("course".value)` line
- You are also returning the value before the conditional statement. So the block below, will never run. Returning a function value ends the function execution

```
if (isValid(document.getElementById("course".value) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Correct Format";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Incorrect Format"
    }
```

Think about functions in terms of inputs and outputs and what function it performs.

For example,

```
/// this function only takes a string and tests if it matches the regex
/// input: string
/// output: true / false (boolean)
function testRegex(text) {
    var myRegExp = /([A-Z]{3})\.\d{3}#\d{4}_(sp|su|fa)-\d{4}/; 
    return myRegExp.test(text)
}

/// this function runs when the button is clicked, calls the testRegex fn
/// and handles setting the output element
/// note: read about ternary conditional operators if confused about ?:
function isValid() {
    const outputEL = document.getElementById("output")
    const courseEl = document.getElementById("course")
    outputEl.innerHTML = testRegex(courseEl.value) ? "Correct Format" : "Incorrect Format";
}
```

If you want to understand how the code is being executed -

- the `script` tags loads your `registerFourth.js` which will contain the two functions I defined above - `isValid` and `testRegex`. Note that the functions are just defined and not executed yet
- when you click the button, the `isValid` function starts executing
- the `isValid` function gets the `output` element and `course` element
- `isValid` then calls `testRegex` with the value of `course` element
- now, `testRegex` runs with the value provided to it and returns (to the calling function, `isValid` is this case) a boolean value, based on if the value is valid
- `isValid` is back in power and depending on the value `testRegex` sent it, it sets `outputEl` to CorrectFormat / Incorrect Format
- `isValid` ends!

Comment: Thank you. I originally had 2 functions, but my teacher specifically gave me feedback to use just one function, which is what has been tripping me up.  I found it easier to understand with 2 separate functions.

Answer (score 1):

this line is invalid

```
return (myRegExp.test(text);
```

If you want to return if the test is true

```
if (myRegExp.test(text)) return;
```

You also need to close the () here with 2 more `)`

```
if (isValid(document.getElementById("course").value))
```

That should solve your syntax issues.  Not your logic though...

Comment: There should be a closing parenthesis after the `"course"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: You need to close the id `"course"` with a parenthesis

Comment: oh, you mean the typo in my solution...  fixed.

Answer (score 1):

1. You miss a few closed brackets.
2. See updated RegExp .
3. Change `document.getElementById("course".value)` to `document.getElementById("course").value`
4. You use of `return` incorrectly, in my code no need `return` .

**see full code :**

```js
function isValid() {

  var text = document.getElementById("course").value;

  var myRegExp = /^([A-Z]{3})\.\d{3}#\d{4}_(sp|su|fa|aa)-\d{4}$/;

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myRegExp.test(text) ? "Correct Format" : "Incorrect Format" ;

}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your course information in the following format AAA.111#2222_aa-1234:</p>

<input type ="text" name ="course" id="course" />

<button onclick="isValid()">Validate</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you tell me what you call this:  ? "Correct Format" : "Incorrect Format" ;     It's not something we've covered in my class.

Comment: @coffeemadness there is no "correct" format. You can format it how you wish. What he was correcting was your "syntax errors." This could be called "correct syntax". Syntax is a set of rules that the javascript language follows.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few syntax errors:

1. `return (myRegExp.test(text);` should be `return myRegExp.test(text);`
2. `isValid(document.getElementById("course".value)` should be `isValid(document.getElementById("course").value)`
3. And finally, putting the return statemenet before the rest of your code defeats the whole purpose of the rest of your code. `return` breaks out of your current function, which means the `if else` statement is rendered useless.

```js
function isValid(text) {
  var myRegExp = "/([A-Z]{3})\.\d{3}#\d{4}_(sp|su|fa)-\d{4}/";
  return myRegExp.test(text);
  if (isValid(document.getElementById("course").value)) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Correct Format";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Incorrect Format"
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Chapter 6 Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Please enter your course information in the following format AAA.111#2222_aa-1234:</p>
  <input type="text" name="course" id="course" />
  <button onclick="isValid()">Validate</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <script src="registerFourth.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```